# Salesforce Implementation Partner

Tags: partner-communities

What is the cost for becoming a Salesforce implementing Partner and sales for authorized agency?
How much is the Royalty and training cost etc?

Brief overview of the steps involved in the process and approximately how long it takes to become a partner.

Comment: Even before discussing costs, this is a great introduction - [AppExchange Partner Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/isvforce_basics) is a trailhead that will give you a nice overview of what it means to be a Partner.

Answer (score 4):

The program fee is based on a matrix, currently located [here](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/Consulting_Partner_Program). It ranges from $1,000 to $25,000 a year, depending on your "trailblazer score." Higher tiers cost more, but gain more benefits as a result. For example, higher tier partners will get better leads from Salesforce, more exposure in marketing material, etc. The actual process typically takes a few weeks to a few months, depending on how many applicants are currently in the queue, the size and complexity of the partner, etc. There is no exact measurement of how long it will take, but instead is variable as partners are added and renewed. You'll want to read the linked resources from the above link for specifics, as they vary from year to year in regards to training, certifications, etc.

The basic process is to get certified (you need a minimum number of certifications to become a partner), apply for partnership, fill out the required contracts, and pay the partner program fee. The programs provide free and discounted training, some free certifications, access to support, marketing referrals, and more, based on the matrices in the above link and the related links you'll find there.

Comment: Thank you. Is there additional training cost other than above mentioned fees?

Comment: @Rajesh It's all in the documentation, again based on a matrix. Self-paced training is free, instructor-led training is at a discount, and a limited number of certification vouchers are free, but additional certifications will still cost. And, of course, you must have a minimum number of certifications in your organization to even become a partner at all, so these would have been obtained at full cost.

Comment: @Rajesh I edited in an additional paragraph for some information I should have included originally, as well.

Comment: Thank you again. I am trying to find cost of instructor- led online training ? Is this in the documentation, grateful if you could post the link here.

Comment: @Rajesh It's a percentage discount based on the cost of the course. You can find the base prices [here](https://www.salesforce.com/services/learn/classes/).